# Running java command and hitting TAB to autocomplete freezes up

Tags: java, macos, terminal

Recently, when I go to run a java program with the command `java` and then hit tab to autocomplete the .class file it just freezes. I have to hit control+c to kill it and I get the message `Killed by signal in _java_class after 4s`. I have tried googling but can't seem to find anything on it. `javac` + tab works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to Java at all. As you state it, the JVM has not even been started. Try to figure out what your shell is trying to do when you hit the tab key for autocomplete.

I guess it might even go scanning the filesystem for a suitable main class and whilst at that running into all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, do you have any idea why my tab function may have changed? As it used to work "normal" and only search the current directory for a suitable main class.